# Groupby Pandas with customized range?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame:

```
 ID       Value
  1           1  
  2           2
  3           1    
  4           1
  5           2
  6           3
  7           4
  8           5  
  9          10  
 10          15
```

I want to groupby by my value and count the ID, in the customized range: <=2, 3-9, >= 10

The results would look like:

```
 Value      ID
 <=2         5
 3-9         3
 >= 10       2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
import numpy as np

labels = ['<=2', '3-9', '>=10']
bins = [0,2,9, np.inf]

df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Value'], bins, labels=labels)).size().to_frame('ID')

# Output

         ID
Value   
 <= 2     5
  3-9     3
 >=10     2
```

Comment: how can I rename the result into what I want?

Comment: @Homesand What do you want to rename here?

Comment: for example: `(0.0, 2.0]` into `<=2`

Comment: @Homesand Updated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need groupby.

```
labels = ['<=2', '3-9', '>=10']
bins = [0,2,9, np.inf]
pd.cut(df['Value'],bins=bins,labels=labels).value_counts().reset_index()
#out[]
index   Value
<=2     5
3-9     3
>=10    2
```